# Azure devops task AddOrUpdateUserAzure@1 failing ubuntu-latest hosted agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

Using AddOrUpdateUserAzure@1 task in Azure pipeline for Microsoft SQL Server database user creation with Microsoft-hosted agent **ubuntu-latest** fails with the error shown below:

```
  - task: AddOrUpdateUserAzure@1
displayName: DB user creation
inputs:
  ConnectedServiceNameSelector: 'ConnectedServiceNameARM'
  ConnectedServiceNameARM: ${{ parameters.arm_service_connection }}
  serverName: test-sql-server'
  databaseName: 'test-sql-db'
  userName: 'admin'
  userPassword: 'admin_password'
  targetUserName: 'readonly-user'
  targetUserPassword: 'password'
  queryTimeout: '30'
```

**Error**

> [Error] The current operating system is not capable of running this task. That typically means the task was written for Windows only. For example, written for Windows Desktop PowerShell.

Please share your suggestion we can create readonly user in Microsoft SQL Server using linux agent

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused because of **Azure Powershell version**.

[image]

I would suggest you to try other version of powershell. Try Azure PowerShell Task version 4.157.4.

Refer this github link -  https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11283

Comment: I am using task: AddOrUpdateUserAzure@1 for the user creation not power shell script for the same

Answer (score 0):

use **sqlcmd** utility available in ubuntu image to execute sql command to create sql login then create user in database and bind role to the user

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: SQL Users
    inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(arm_service_connection)
        scriptType: bash
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
            password=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9_!@#$%^&*()\-+=' | head -c16)
            # db user login creation
            sqlcmd -S $(servername).database.windows.net \
              -U $(resource_prefix)-master \
              -P $(sql_admin_password) -I \
              -Q "CREATE LOGIN [$(new_db_login_name)] WITH PASSWORD= '$password';"
            # db user creation
            sqlcmd -S $(servername).database.windows.net \
              -d $(databasename) \
              -U $(admin_username) \
              -P $(sql_admin_password) -I \
              -Q "CREATE USER [$(new_username)] FOR LOGIN [$(new_db_login_name)] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo];"
            # db user role assignment
            sqlcmd -S $(servername).database.windows.net \
              -d $(databasename) \
              -U $(admin_username) -P $(sql_admin_password) -I \
              -Q "ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [$(new_username)];"
```